# Grafana + Zabbix 2 item in 1 Stat

Tags: grafana, monitoring, zabbix

There are visualizations - Stat. It has 2 or more queries from the same Host! And they are combined using Transform - Merge. But when a problematic Item is found, the indication will only respond to the last Item that was added.
Example:
Request (A) - Item (Service Status "A") - Service Running (Green!)
Request (B) - Item (Service Status "C") - Service Not Active (Red!)
Request (C) - Item (Service Status "C") - Service running (Green!)
This statistic ignores that request (B) is not active and will show information on request (C).
Is it possible to make / implement so that the data parameters change dynamically, is this either already implemented, I did not find it?

Transform - Sort by was used, but sorts by one parameter, so Merge - merges all Hosts and the Item specified in them into ONE!